# Positive, Negative and Neutral Button are invisible in my app

Tags: android

The class extends DialogFragment

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    builder.setTitle("Aviso")
            .setMessage("Vas a pasar a estado Ocupado, estás seguro?")
            .setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                        }
                    }
            )
            .setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                }
            })
            .setNeutralButton("Más Tarde", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                }
            });

    return builder.create();
}
}
```

This is the call to the Dialog on the java file

```
protected void BotonRojo(View view){
    DialogFragment dialogFragment = new DialogoOcupado();
    dialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"Un Dialogo");
    tv.setText("OCUPADO");
}
```

Buttons are there, I can click them but the text does not appear

[image]

Comment: using any style???

Comment: your `colorAccent` is white?

Comment: but you can still click it?

Comment: These buttons are visible on another mobile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this...

```
<style name="AppCompatAlertDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="colorAccent">#546E7A</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#37474F</item>
    <item name="android:background">#B0BEC5</item>
</style>
```

and

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
```

Replace this

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(), R.style.AppCompatAlertDialogStyle);
```